# IE 8 stopped working during website loading

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance

When testing my site compatibility on IE8, the site load at once but the IE8 browser crashes. Please see the link http://labelco.staging.wpengine.com/. Can any body tell me what is causing the IE8 to stop responding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Add http://browsehappy.com/ to your website :) Seriously, who uses IE 8 anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors that are being thrown and logged to console. If IE doesn't have a console open (your dev tools are open), log statements will crash your page. Firefox and Chrome are smart enough to deal with it. IE, unsurprisingly, is not.

Hit F12 to open your dev tools, and your app will finish loading. (Obviously you'll have to fix the underlying issue to get it to work properly.)